# Schema type for "Bookmark" items

Tags: microdata, schema.org, microformats

Is there an appropriate schema type for bookmark items such as in Reddit, Digg, etc.?

Is it OK to use the "Article"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

article is appropriate for a blogpost, so that makes sense to me. there is no specification for bookmarks in schema.org. i would use `rel="tag"` to implement microformats. microformats are not the same thing as schema.org/microdata. schema.org article: http://schema.org/Article microformats tag: http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-tag

Comment: Currently I'm using xFolk: http://microformats.org/wiki/xfolk for my site. Maybe I just stay put on it.